# Tracking Installs with Inno Installer

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using the Inno installer for my application.

I've been trying to figure out how to track how many app installations I get.  I've been using browser popup after install, but would like to do it with the installer rather than a popup.

Can't find and addons. So I'm wondering if anyone has done this.

Should I just stick with the popup?

Comment: What do you want to track exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could always have your installer use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)
 to make a call out to your webpage...

You could just drop the curl program in the temp folder for the install... execute the call to your page and then delete curl from the temp directory.  Of course they could block they could block the call with a personal firewall but that is not any different then them blocking your popup.  This would be hidden for the most part which is what I think you are looking for.

You could always write a pascal script right in innosetup to do the call utilizing the [winhttp library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384045%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Or you could just write a vbscript and execute that with the cscript engine to do the same http call.

That should point you to at least 3 different options to do what you need.

Comment: also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871895/http-post-request-in-inno-setup-script

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have not solved the issue I came across this post that will help. it is a script that will post data via http post

[HTTP POST request in Inno Setup Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871895/http-post-request-in-inno-setup-script)

hope this helps. i am planning to use is my self and i will post a comment to let you know if it worked out