# Inno Setup - Uninstall

Tags: inno-setup

Does anyone know how to do an HTTP post to a URL upon completion of uninstall?  I'd like to track in my database total number of uninstalls.

Comment: For instance [`this way`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6722816/960757).

Comment: There is also uninstall feedback described [here](http://www.gerixsoft.com/blog/innosetup/uninstall-feedback)

Comment: Btw, I'm having a simple HTTP/S request/response library on my task list. But first I want to finish the [`Inno JSON Parser`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-json-parser/wiki/Reference), then the similar library for XML files and then this one. But I'm busy with my daily work as well, so it will take some time.