# INNO setup serial number validating failing?

Tags: c#, validation, inno-setup

Im trying to validate the serial number entered by the user on server side with the help of webservice,,, when the user enters the serial key and clicks the next button, the serial number should be validated..i used the code below for that....the name of my method that validates the serial number is ValidateKey()....and im passing a static value 123456 for that method and service will return false for this value,,,,but my installation is proceeding further and im getting the alert messagebox at the last step of my installation

```
function ValidateSerialNumber: Boolean;
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
begin
  WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
  WinHttpReq.Open('POST', 'http://localhost:1024/WebService1/Service.asmx?op=ValidateMe', False);
  WinHttpReq.Send('123456');

  if WinHttpReq.Status <> 200 then
  begin
    Result := False;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if CurPageID = SerialPage.ID then
  begin
    Result := ValidateSerialNumber;
  end;
end;
```

here i want to installation to stop when the user clicks the next button if the service returns false, if the service returns true then he can go further with the installation, where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to validate that serial number from the [`NextButtonClick`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#NextButtonClick) event method. To stay on your custom page if the validation fails assign `False` value to the `Result` variable. If you want to let the wizard continue, assign `True` to the `Result` of that event method. Something like this:

```
function ValidateSerialNumber(const SerialNumber: string): Boolean;
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
begin
  Result := False;

  WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
  WinHttpReq.Open('POST', 'http://localhost:1024/WebService1/Service.asmx?op=ValidateMe', False);
  WinHttpReq.Send(SerialNumber);

  Result := WinHttpReq.Status = 200;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  SerialNumber: string;
begin
  Result := True;

  if CurPageID = SerialPage.ID then
  begin
    SerialNumber := GetSerialNumber('-');
    Result := ValidateSerialNumber(SerialNumber);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: yes thanku...this is working fine but with small issues, first thing when it is false i want to show a message on the screen not a valid serial key to the user , also how can i get the serial number entered by the user and store it in a variable?...i edited my question with the changes what i made

Comment: Proper way would be to ask another question. This question asked how to stop when the user clicks the next button if the service returns False, for which I've answered and you've accepted that. I'll expand my answer this time, but please do not do it this way. There should be one question per post. Moreover, accepting answer means that the post resolved your question, which also means that you won't change the question after that. Thanks!

Comment: In which format do you want that serial number ? The `GetSerialNumber` by which you can get the entered string supports delimiter char. Or do you have any different requirements ?

Comment: I've made an update, which shows how to get and store the serial number delimited by the `-` char from the page I wrote a code some time ago. Anyway, do you think that your web service returns status different from 200 when the user enters invalid serial number ? Doesn't it return status 200, but the answer in response text ? In any case, this would be topic for a different question...

Comment: thanks a lot for sparing ur time..everything is working fine now