# How to catch OleObject exception in Inno Setup?

Tags: winapi, exception, inno-setup, pascal, ole

So I try to make a post request having no internet connection using [next modified code:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6722816/1973207)

```
      WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
      WinHttpReq.Open('POST', '<your_web_server>', false);
      WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      try
        WinHttpReq.Send('data');
      except
           bla:= 'e';
      finally
           bla := 'f';
      end;
```

Yet exception does not get catched and I get crush of my setup application with next image:

[image]

How to handle OleObject exception in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is incomplete, but `try..except` block catches all the exceptions, including those thrown by OLE objects. However, your screenshot shows the line number, where the exception was thrown, and so you were running debugger.

And debugger shows all exception messages regardless they are in a `try..except` block, unless you uncheck *"Pause on exceptions"* option in Inno Setup IDE settings:

[image]

By default is this option enabled (which I would recommend to keep), which means that all exceptions are reported as exception messages and that's what might have mislead you. If you were running your setup without debugger attached, you wouldn't see that exception message.