# SOAP Web Service with Inno Setup

Tags: web-services, soap, inno-setup

While using Inno Setup to create an installer a need as arisen to verify a user's credentials during the installation process. The application has been out in production for a while and the only need to move to an installer is due to support for NPAPI within web browsers being deprecated. There is already a way that the application verifies a user's credentials before launching the application that I'm trying to take advantage of, which is through a SOAP request. The verification process is just not making sure the user is authorized but also assigning them a token that prevents their information from having to be sent multiple times during the running of the application.

My question, is there a way to make the SOAP request to verify a user's credentials through during the installation process? If so, how would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP is just an XML over HTTP.

So you can use the [`WinHttpRequest` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest):

```pascal
WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'http://soapserver.example.com/', False);
WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8');
WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader('SOAPAction', '...');
WinHttpReq.Send('<data/>');
{ WinHttpReq.ResponseText will hold the SOAP response }
```

See also [HTTP POST request in Inno Setup Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4871895/850848).

---

To parse the SOAP response, you can use the [`Msxml2.DOMDocument` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms756987(v=vs.85)):

[How to read and write XML document node values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11250266/850848)