# Inno Setup read file on web server

Tags: inno-setup

I'm not really sure if this is possible or where to start, but what I am trying to do is not allow a user to run the setup if a serial number located on my web server doesn't exist. I am trying to keep it simple and just checking to see if a file exists.....like the setup checks my website is file 1234.txt exists. 
If the file exists, the installer allows the setup to begin, if not it doesn't.

Is there a way to do this in inno setup or would I need to call another .exe program first in some way?

Thanks

Comment: There is code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4871895/62576) that shows how to submit an HTTP Post request to a web server. You can alter it to just request the license file instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ken, you are a legend